# How can I add enumerate with two colums into tabularray like task package?

Tags: tabularray

I am using task package

```
\begin{tasks}[label = \alph*)](2)
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \end{tasks}
```

How can I this into `tabularray`. I must do this by hand

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.7cm, vmargin={1.8cm,1.7cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, counter,
    diagbox, siunitx,  varwidth}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{normal}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{normal}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{normal}{}
\SetTblrTemplate{caption-text}{normal}{}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\newcounter{prob}
\NewTableCommand\problem[1]{\SetRow{bg=gray9}%
    \SetCell[r=#1]{h, cmd={\stepcounter{prob}\theprob}, bg=white}}

\begin{document}
    I am using task package
    \begin{tasks}[label = \alph*)](2)
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \end{tasks}
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption={Answer}]{hlines, vlines,
            colspec = {Q[c, h, font=\bfseries] X[valign=h] Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]},
            cell{1}{2-3}={halign=c},
            row{1} = {yellow9, font=\bfseries, mode=text},
            rowsep = 5pt,
            rowhead = 1,
        } 
    Problem & Content  & Point    \\
        \problem{1} &   Prolbem 1
        
        a)  $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$ \quad  b) $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$ &1,00
    \end{longtblr} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tasks`, I can set up the number of columns by change 2 to another number in this code.

```
\begin{tasks}[label = \alph*)](2)
        \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
        \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
        \end{tasks}
```

Comment: What are you asking how to do exactly? Do you want to produce the same output from different input? Or do you want different output from the same input? Or different output from different input? It is not straightforward to increment counters in `tabularray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.7cm, vmargin={1.8cm,1.7cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, counter,
                diagbox, siunitx,  varwidth}

\begin{document}
I am using task package
    \begin{tasks}[label = \alph*)](2)
\task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
\task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \end{tasks}
    
\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Answer}]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {Q[c, h, font=\bfseries] 
                             X[h, preto=\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}, appto=\end{minipage}] 
                             Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]},
                  cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\the\numexpr\arabic{rownum}-1},
                  row{1} = {c, bg=yellow9, font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                  rowsep = 5pt,
                  hspan=minimal,
                  rowhead = 1,
    }
Problem & \centering Content  & Point    \\
    &   \begin{tasks}[label = \alph*)](2)
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
        \end{tasks}
        &   1,00                \\
    &   \begin{tasks}[label = \alph*)](2)
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
    \task $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$
        \end{tasks}
        &   1,00                \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

(I reduce your document example to MWE, issues for caption formatting you can add yourself).

[image]

Comment: How can I align center at row 1 like my picture?

Comment: @Laurenso, yes you can. Just ad `\centering` before  content od the second cell. See edited answer (will appear soon).

Comment: Thank you very much.